# Export the whole database on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to export the whole database in mongodb instead of exporting a collection this way?

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d3de201b128f8eccc1979a5"},"user":"myuser","password":"$2y$10$euzVCeHJ4XAT0xQuQzUotenktVGCQ5darCSWWQtfYE80IqLovDNfi","widgets":[{"name":"w1","color":"blue"},{"name":"w2","color":"green"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes  please  use `mongodump`
Some parameters are as follow

```
--db <database>, -d <database>
```

If you do not specify a database, `mongodump` copies all databases in this instance into the dump files.

```
--collection <collection>, -c <collection>
```

If you do not specify a collection, this option copies all collections in the specified database or instance to the dump files.

so  with your condition  you can do it like this

```
mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password "pass"   --db yourdatabasename  --out /opt/backup/mongodumpdir
```

the default  host port  is localhost & 27017   .
If you haven't changed the default, you can ignore this

Answer (score 0):

`mongodump` is a way to do this.
See the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)